# Use BPY to List objects by the most number of tris

Tags: python, polycount

I am working on optimizing a large file and would like to use a script to print a list of the objects and their triangle count for objects visible in the scene in order of least number of triangles to most.

It would be great to also be able to export this as a CSV spread sheet file, but maybe that's off topic for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Get all visible mesh Tris

```
import bpy

lis = []
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type != 'MESH': continue
    if not obj.visible_get(): continue

    lis.append((obj.name, sum([(len(p.vertices) - 2) for p in obj.data.polygons])))

lis.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

for el in lis:
    print(el)
```

##### Export as CSV

```
import bpy

lis = []
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type != 'MESH': continue
    if not obj.visible_get(): continue

    lis.append((obj.name, sum([(len(p.vertices) - 2) for p in obj.data.polygons])))

lis.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

outputFile = 'C:/yourlocation/list.csv'

line = ["Name, Tris\n"]
for el in lis:
    line.append(f'{el[0]},{el[1]}\n')

f = open(outputFile, 'w')
f.writelines(line)
f.close()
```